# Response Redirect Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in mvc response redirect. In my code everything seems to be right, code goes into it, does the right thing but page doesn't refresh. My function is triggered by a button and the function has a response redirect code.

Here is my code. It goes to Home/Index, I can see it while I'm debugging but the home view doesn't show.

**Note : First page is Login View**

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    [IntranetAction]
    public ActionResult User()
    {         
        return View();
    }

    public void checkAuthentication(UserLoginInfo loginInfo)
    {         
        bool isAuthenticated = new LdapServiceManager().isAuthenticated(loginInfo);
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {      
            Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("/", false);
        }         
    }
```

## HomeController Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (IsDbExists())
    {
        _contactList = new List<Contact>();         

        UpdateOperations();
        return View(_contactList);
    }

    Response.Redirect("/Loading/LoadingScreen");
    return null;
}
```

## Button CSHTML

```
$("#LoginButton")
    .click(function() {
        if ($("#usernameBox").val() == '') {
            $("#usernameField").addClass('has-error');
            $('#usernameSpan').css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $("#usernameField").removeClass('has-error');           
        }
        if ($("#passwordBox").val() == '') {
            $("#passwordField").addClass('has-error');
            $('#passwordSpan').css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $("#passwordField").removeClass('has-error');
        }

        if ($("#usernameBox").val() != "" && $("#passwordBox").val() != "") {

            $.post("/Login/checkAuthentication",
            {
                username: $("#usernameBox").val(),
                password: $("#passwordBox").val()
            });
        }
    });
```

The yellow line can go to index but nothing changes on display

Comment: try using the Redirect action instead.  return Redirect("yoururl");

Comment: You need to return something (not `null`) - `return Redirect(...);` or `return RedirectToAction(...);` and you method needs to be `public ActionResult checkAuthentication(UserLoginInfo loginInfo)`

Comment: My homepage is loginView. I missed it to write

Comment: Based on your edit, your making an ajax call - ajax never redirects (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page)

Comment: try using this : `return Redirect("/oops/");`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `RedirectToAction`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (IsDbExists())
    {
        _contactList = new List<Contact>();         

        UpdateOperations();
        return View(_contactList);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("actionname", "controllername");
}
```

returning `null` is mostly wrong :)

Comment: Are you sure about it? My problem is between Login Controller and Home Controller Index. I can go into if(IsDbExist()) everytime. Also i can go into return View(_contactList);

Comment: Then "return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");" and remove the Response.End()

Comment: Ahh You called this in checkAuthentication which returns void. You have to call this on an action directly. Show me the function where you call checkAuthentication

Comment: okay, since this is a JavaScript-call now (that was a neccessary information!!), my last Idea would be to make `checkAuthentication`returning an `ActionResult` instead of `void` and then return the `RedirectToAction("action", "controller")` - but no idea if this really works...

Comment: if this doesn't work, I'd suggest you to really use MVCs `@Html.BeginForm()` when doing something with buttons, submitting, etc...